# PostgreSQL COPY command issues

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

In my Postgresql database I have created a table called `NAV_DATA` with five columns:

```
 id (PKEY)
,name (VARCHAR)
,call_type (VARCHAR)
,date_created (date)
```

For these columns I have the csv file which the delimiter TAB `\t` and Quotechar `"`.
It also has some empty fields in middle column.

How to allow to accept null values in copy command?

I want to insert the columns `(name, call_type, date_created)`. I don't have the field `id` in my csv.

How to copy specific columns into the DB?

The issue is also with delimiter TAB `\t`?

Comment: Please take a look at the [appropriate page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) of the manual and modify your question if you see anything unclear.

Comment: You mention "5 columns", but show only 4?

Answer (score 2):

```
copy "NAV_DATA" (name,call_type,date_created) from 'c:/test.txt' with delimiter '\t' csv
```

Comment: I think the table name shouldn't be in quotes.The doubt is Is that primary key ID will be incremented automatically for every records?

Comment: Postgres is case sensitive for table and column names and unless surrounded by qoutes it will convert to lower case. this will mean that NAV_DATA wont match a table called NAV_DATA. You would have to write "NAV_DATA" in your query.

Comment: You can use a sequence like has been suggested by Erwin. Personally when I import CSV's I import into a table that matched the CSV struture and then use SQL queries to copy from the imported dirty table in to my clean tables. This way you can TRIM spaces, set NULLs, create sequences and run the query DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you wonder about how `NULL` values are represented in the CSV file have a look at the **manual** page @Milen is linking to in his comment. Or write some test data (including `NULL` values) into your table and export it with `COPY TO`. You get exactly the format that is expected for `COPY FROM`.

In the standard format `NULL` is represented by `\N`, in standard `CSV` format by *nothing* between the delimiters. And columns not mentioned in the `COPY` command will be filled in with their respective defaults.

A serial column for instance (like `id` probably) will get `nextval()` from the associated sequence for every row. If `id` doesn't have a default yet, [create a sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) for it and make `nextval('my_sequence_name')` the column default.